# Why are there so many fire incidents happening around the world?

Tags: four-elements

Recently there was fire in Australia and before that there was fire in USA.
In India fire incidents keep happening.

My question is given the fact fire is a natural element, what causes such fire disasters?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems as an attempt to discuss climate change.

Comment: It's a total valid and good question, reaching till high Abhidhamma. Rupa requires nama.

Answer (score 2):

Cosmic order is governed by the 5 [Niyama Dhamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niyama):

> 1. `utu-niyāma` “the constraint of the seasons”, i.e. in certain regions of the earth at certain periods the flowering and fruiting of trees all at one time (ekappahāreneva), the blowing or ceasing of wind, the degree of the heat of the sun, the amount of rain-fall, some flowers like the lotuses opening during the day and closing at night and so on;
> 2. `bīja-niyāma` “the constraint of seeds or germs”, i.e. a seed producing its own kind as barley seed produces barley;
> 3. `kammaniyāma` “the constraint of kamma”, i.e. good actions produce good results and bad actions produce bad results. This constraint is said to be epitomised by [Dhammapada] verse 127 which explains that the consequences of actions are inescapable;
> 4. `citta-niyāma` “the constraint of mind”, i.e. the order of the process of mind-activities as the preceding thought-moment causing and conditioning the succeeding one in a cause and effect relation;
> 5. `dhamma-niyāma` “the constraint of dhammas”, i.e. such events like the quaking of the ten thousand world-systems at the Bodhisatta’s conception in his mother’s womb and at his birth. At the end of the discussion Sumaṅgalavilāsinī passage the Commentary says that dhammaniyāma explains the term dhammatā in the text of the Mahāpadāna Sutta (D ii.12) (Cf. S 12.20 for a discussion of the use of the word dhammaniyamatā in the suttas)

Bush and forest fires generally happen due to dry weather which is `utu-niyāma`.

Comment: Good answer. Smartly you have avoided the assumption of anomaly in fire incidents ... everything is normal. But if one keeps ignoring the truth then how will one learn ?

Comment: And "Bush and forest fires generally happen due to dry weather which is utu-niyāma.": isn't weather and place of dwelling a matter of Upanissaya (strong condition causes, kamma, tendecy), spoken in Abhidhamma means, Upasaka Sirinath? What about bringing it in relation with the "Fire ceremony" and attachment to sensuality? In lesser sensual attached areas there might be cooler weather or?